# Prevent user to uninstall application from android phone

Tags: motorola-moto-g, uninstallation

I have `Moto G5 Plus Android phone`. I don't want to allow someone to uninstall the application from my android phone. The android phone allows to press on the application and drag it to delete icon and allow uninstallation. 
I want if someone does the same operation in my phone then before uninstall it ask password or pattern lock.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a user tries to uninstall an app through the home launcher, Settings app, or through any third-party app, the system app Package Installer is invoked and user is asked to confirm the uninstallation. So the solution for you is to either disable that Package Installer app (or at least its component which is invoked for user confirmation) or find an app locker which can lock this system app.

I tried some app locker apps and found that [AppLock - Fingerprint](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sp.protector.free) can lock down Package Installer app. It even recommends it. From then on, anyone trying to uninstall an app would need to authenticate  with your preferred choice of authentication before proceeding to uninstall. At the risk of redundancy, this does take care  of uninstallation via Settings app too, as I explained the reason for it in the beginning.

**Note:** app locker apps alike many privacy protector apps are notorious for floundering a user's privacy and shoving ads down the user's throat.

Comment: For one phone, this is likely the best answer... but I don't understand why this would be an issue (children perhaps?) If this is in a corporate/enterprise environment than it is a textbook case for the use of an MDM like Airwatch, Codeproof, InTune,  or Meraki to manage security and package management.

Comment: @Firelord, Thanks to its working fine for Moto G5 Plus.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible. The other way to uninstall app is going to Settings and under usually **Applications** where you can uninstall the apps easily.

What you can do instead is move your app as a System app, but it needs your phone to be rooted. System apps cannot be uninstalled easily without the person having the knowledge how to uninstall it. Systems apps are like your Messaging, Dialer, Gallery Apps, if you'll notice there is no uninstall option but disable option only.

Comment: While converting 3rd party apps to system app could prevent uninstall, its not a solution if the user does not want to root their phone. However the answer by @Firelord is totally possible and viable

Comment: @Beveloper yes, **if** only the user does not want to. But OP's post has no indication that he is not accepting rooted suggestions nor saying only non-root method.